# One array of integers or two arrays of booleans?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, memory, integer, boolean

I have to store a lot of variables inside of two-dimensional arrays to use them later and use as little memory as possible.

(the array is a table which represents pixels in a pygame screen, some pixels are "on fire", some are "flammable" and some are "non-flammable", so each pixel, or array element, can be in one of these three states)

I have 2 options:
1) I can use one array of integers, which will take values of 0,1 or 2
2) Or I can use two arrays of booleans (there will be exactly twice as many booleans as integers)

If I want to use less memory, which should I choose? Or is there a solution that will be better than both of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something for you to play around with:

```
from sys import getsizeof
a = [True, False, None, True, False, None]
b = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
print (getsizeof (a))
print (getsizeof (b))
```

This will show you how much memory your lists are using.